# Which are the safest deposit banks worldwide (according to reputable rating agencies)?

Tags: banking, credit-score, security, credit-rating-agency

I would like to know which global banks are the safest for holding money, and though the big three rating agencies are often used to estimate credit worthiness of financial institutions, this seems unwise as they were at best useless for the Great Recession.  Are there any ratings or analysis of world banks by risk of collapse... by someone reputable ([not the big three](https://www.usatoday.com/story/money/business/2013/09/13/credit-rating-agencies-2008-financial-crisis-lehman/2759025/))?

Comment: Are you looking to invest in the bank company, or are you interested in where to put your money? In one case the national insurance may play a bigger role in the analysis.

Comment: @mhoran_psprep I am wondering where is safe to deposit money.

Comment: This question might be more on topic if you altered it to ask about the ratings or metrics used to determine a banks safety and stability.

Comment: The question cannot be answered without knowing how much money you are thinking about. If it is less than 100,000 EUR then any bank that is regulated by the ECB and thus covered by the European Deposit Insurance Scheme would probably be categorized as some of the all time safest banks. If you are thinking about more than 100,000 EUR equivalent, then the answer changes.

Answer (score 1):

The question isn't which bank is safest, it is which system is safest based on your situation.

In the US a bank or credit union with FDIC/NCUA coverage will protect the money in the account. Other countries have similar systems. You have to pick the country not just on the insurance but also based on your ability to get to the funds with little friction.

Once you have picked the country then you have to pick a financial institution within that system.  You will have to research the government and non-government rating systems. Many countries tightened their banking systems after the 2008 crisis. In the US you have to look at details related to stress testing.

But if the insurance is solid, and backstopped by the national government, then the biggest risk isn't loss of money, it is loss of access. You have to understand how long you lose access to your funds if the bank fails. Is it measured in hours, days, or weeks?

If you are dealing with a large amount of money, you might have to split the funds across accounts, or even across institutions to stay under the protection limits.